# Magento 2: Error during VAT Number verification

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, vat

I'm trying to set VAT code for my shop in Store>Configuration and then `General>General>Store Information.`

I've set country, region, city, zip, street and, of course, VAT number (without country code) all correctly but when I click on **"Validate VAT Number"** it gives me **"Error during VAT Number verification."** and I can't work out why it says so.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? We have the same problem. The same VAT works on other Magento 2 sites (tested).

Comment: Unfortunately no, I haven't. If you find it, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to webninjas's answer (as it worked for me, I was also missing SOAP), specifically run:

```
apt install php 7.0-soap

service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was a missing PHP SOAP extension on server. After installing that the VAT validation started working.